# add unique form for each tab in react

Tags: reactjs, tabs

> hello guys, i have tabs in my web app. i want generate new form for each tab when tab is created. actually want pass new form to each tab content.

i'm really confused!

**here is my code:**

```
handleAddTab = () => {
    const { tabs } = this.state;

    const newTabObject = {
      id: uuid(),
      name: `Tab ${tabs.length + 1}`,
      content: `Hell`
    };

    this.setState({
      tabs: [...tabs, newTabObject],
      currentTab: newTabObject,
      editMode: false,
      editTabNameMode: false
    });
  };
```

wish someone answer me

Comment: What is the problem that you are encountering?

Comment: I need add form to each created tabs, but when I fill the form in a tab, all forms has the same value. need to generate a unique form for each tab. like postman tabs that when you click on plus button generate a tab with a new form.
this may help to understand better:
https://codesandbox.io/s/tab-creator-forked-nxh3m?file=/src/index.js